# JQuery UI DatePicker has no style

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to display a JQuery UI datepicker widjet, using the example from their website.
The problem is that when the datepicker is displayed there is no style, see the code below.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
         <!-- <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
               $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
            });
        </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have tested locally in the file system and tested using node simple server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load jQueryUI through Google, make sure the jQueryUI CSS theme has the same version as the jQueryUI library.

And not use `src` for link css, use `href` to link.

For example:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Worked [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jm5c4qby/13/)

Answer (score 4):

To include CSS,

Use **`href`** : `<link rel="stylesheet" href=".."`

and not `src` :  <strike>`<link rel="stylesheet" src=".."`</strike>

---

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check below code....I have changed **CSS**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"><!--Replace this line-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include a CSS file for the theme. You can download your themes from here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

You need to include following files:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

You can use the latest versions ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>

</html>
```